# Generator is not defined

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to test for an ES6 generator with this code:

```
thegenerator instanceof Generator
```

However I keep getting `ReferenceError: Generator is not defined`

It's also weird because I get this when I treat it as an `Array`

```
TypeError: Object [object Generator] has no method 'indexOf'
```

Comment: Can you post a demo to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Type of generators are function.

Comment: @elclanrs I don't know if that's possible with ES6. But it's just that first one liner.

Comment: Yes, Chrome and FF support generators natively, or try jsfiddle or jsbin with Babel.

Comment: Generators are of type Object

Comment: Also, there are a few questions here in SO, look for "check if function is generator" for answers.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tpe6vdz2/2/

Comment: @adeneo but how to distinguish? https://jsfiddle.net/7gwravha/

Comment: @adeneo, indeed my mistake, generator itself is indeed an object, i was talking about generator function. var gen = function* () {};

Comment: https://jsbin.com/tehusafeca/edit?js,console

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just compare the constructor, as it's inherited it should be the same as a new generator

```
thegenerator.constructor === (function*(){}()).constructor;
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/tpe6vdz2/4/)

Comment: It's worth mentioning _why_ it's not available - the reason is you shouldn't care if something is a generator or not - and these checks are frail and will fail with subclasses or in compile time

Answer (score 2):

You can use the constructor.name property to figure out.

```
function isGenerator(name) {
    return name === 'GeneratorFunction';
}

console.log(isGenerator(gen.constructor.name)); // true
console.log(isGenerator(normal.constructor.name)); // false
```

Otherwise they are pretty much indistinguishable.

```
const gen = function*() {};
const normal = function() {};

console.log(gen.constructor); // GeneratorFunction()
console.log(typeof gen); // function
console.log(gen instanceof Function); // true
console.log(gen instanceof Object); // true

console.log(normal.constructor); // Function()
console.log(typeof normal); // function
console.log(normal instanceof Function); // true
console.log(normal instanceof Object); // true

console.log(gen.constructor.name); // 'GeneratorFunction'
console.log(normal.constructor.name); // 'Function'
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7gwravha/2/

Answer (score 2):

Try using `Object.getPrototypeOf()` , `.toString()`

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(thegenerator).toString() === "[object Generator]"
```

Comment: I was interested in your code so I ran it: https://jsfiddle.net/36dc4n8j/ , but I got an error:  `Function.prototype.toString is not generic`

Comment: It's false now :/ returns [Object object]

Comment: @AR7 At jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/36dc4n8j/1/ `Object.getPrototypeOf(thegenerator.prototype).toString() === "[object Generator]"` returns `true` , here , at chromium 49 , where `thegenerator` is `const thegenerator = function*() {};`

Comment: Ah I'm on `Google Chrome: 47.0.2526.106 (Official Build)` that might be the problem

Comment: @jasonszhao _"get this when I treat it as an Array"_ Note,  `Generator` is not an `Array`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100319/discussion-between-guest271314-and-ar7).